# Как вывести надпись о том что товар — хит продаж Opencart 3

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

В гугле ничего не нашел, может плохо гуглил.
По типу такого:
[image: По типу такого:=]

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду что как такую кнопку сделать или как сдлеать при добавление в базу данных чтоб это кнопка загоралась?

Comment: Скорее второе. Если товар входит в список хитов продаж, то на его странице появлялась надпись "Хит продаж"

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю это [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NljSihCxbRU) вам поможет, для этого нужны хоть какие-нибудь знания на php, надеюсь вы разберетесь